# ios Glitches in table view cell image

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am new to swift language...
Making simple table with image, and want to set corner radius of image view inside cell.

Code :-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)!

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

    if(cell.imageView != nil){
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "avatar")
        cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius =  cell.imageView!.frame.size.height/2
        cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }


    return cell
}
```

Don't know what i am doing wrong, but corner radius not seted when table display when i start to scroll table it set properly ...[image]

Edit:-
Getting fine result with `cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius =  20`
Don't know why it works with static value.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout ?

Comment: @technerd, yes i am using it ..

Comment: ImageView size is fixed or depend on aspect ratio ?

Comment: I have only set constraints to table view not to cell or cell.contentview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens due to ImageView is still not getting Width or Height value at time tableView loading first time.
You must have to pass Width and Height of imageView inside cell in Storyboard.

If you are not passing Width or height then reload table view in viewDidAppear method.

You can set Constraint for ImageView in Cell as suggested in image.

[image]

[image]

Output :

[image]

Apply Corner radius when creating cell.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:9];

NSLog(@"Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(imgView.frame));

imgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.size.width/2.0;
imgView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
//imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;

UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:99];
if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){

    lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Index : %ld -- I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....I am Even....",(long)indexPath.row];

}else{

    lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Index : %ld -- I am Odd....I am Odd....I am Odd....I am Odd....I am Odd....I am Odd....I am Odd....I am Odd....",(long)indexPath.row];

}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @technerd, it's working in viewDidAppear but it show after few mili second, i tried to put in willAppear but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Any other solution if i don't want to show it to user at first.

Comment: How can i set width height of imageView in cell for default image view , not by adding custom image view

Comment: please find edited answer to set Constraint for ImageView .

Comment: i don't find image in cell ... we can add it but i think we should make it custom. 
Is there anyway to add this constraint in Default image view of cell.

Comment: As suggested in image, just put UIImageView in cell and apply constraint as highlighted in Image.

Comment: Please find edited answer, follow steps as suggested and you will get proper result.

Comment: thanks for answer ..
I know we can do in this way... but i am looking for solution without customising cell. default cell provide image view so why we need to add other imageView .....finally i think it's not possible to edit default imageView (cell.imageView) of cell through storyBoard. anyway @technerd thanks again for answer ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your own imageView, it's better to set the cornerRadius inside the custom TableViewCell.

```
class CircularTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var circularImageView: UIImageView!
override func layoutSubviews() {
    circularImageView.layer.cornerRadius = circularImageView.bounds.height / 2
    circularImageView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Note the cornerRadius property can't guarantee that the view will be absolutely round unless you set the imageView's width and height ratio to be 1:1. Another approach to create round view is using Mask.

Comment: Please check edited post , it works with static value... do you have any idea on it ...

Answer (score 0):

your code is true but code is sorting error

this is :

```
cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius =  cell.imageView!.frame.size.height/2
cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "avatar")
```